# How to save a video using code in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have captured a video using objective c,however I am not able to save it in the iphone photos library.I dont want to use the AlAssets library,I want to use the image picker only.I have seen a lot of methods on stack overflow and other sites but they either use storage location path(which is not mentioned what it is) or they dont work.
This is my piece of code.

```
-(IBAction)Onclick:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController

                                             alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes =  [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)

                               kUTTypeMovie];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    //UISaveVideoAtPath
    imagePicker.allowsImageEditing = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:imagePicker.view];
    [imagePicker viewWillAppear:YES];

    CGRect overlayFrame = CGRectMake(0, 380, 320, 44);
    //UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    UIView *baseView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
    baseView.backgroundColor =[UIColor greenColor];
    //lbl.text=@"dfgfdgfd";
    baseView.frame=overlayFrame;
    //view.delegate = self;
    //view.picker = picker;
    //[view customize];
    imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = baseView;


    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES]; 


}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){
        UIImage *picture = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(picture, nil, nil, nil);
    }
    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]){

        NSURL *url = [[[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] copy] autorelease];

//        ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
//        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url
//                                    completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){/*notify of completion*/}];
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(url, nil, nil, nil);
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info
{
        NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

         [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        // Handle a movie capture
        if (CFStringCompare (( CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
            == kCFCompareEqualTo)
        {

            NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:
                                    UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
            if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath))
            {
                UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath,self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
            }


        }
    }
}
- (void)video:(NSString*)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError*)error contextInfo:(void*)contextInfo
{
    if (error)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Photo/Video Saving Failed"  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Photo/Video Saved" message:@"Saved To Photo Album"  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
       /*notify of completion*/
       NSLog(@"AssetURL: %@",assetURL);
       NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
       if (!error) {
            //video saved

       }else{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.domain delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];
       }

}];
```